# How to Access Windows Environment Variable in Azure Dev Ops Build Pipline?

Tags: azure-devops, environment-variables

Many of our C++ projects reference a custom environment variable set through Control Panel > System and Security > System > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables > System variables.  This is simply a path to various required libraries.  For example, Key: LibraryLocation, Value: C:\libraries, referenced in code by $(LibraryLocation).

I assumed this would automatically be found without me needing to define it as part of the build pipeline but our builds fail, even if I add a copy of this key-value pair under Pipeline variables, or as a MSBuild parameter:

```
/p:LibraryLocation=$(LibraryLocation) //fails
/p:LibraryLocation="C:\libraries" //fails
```

All of the above attempts produce the following in the debug output:

```
/IC:\libraries\Boost\v1.70.0\include //notice the lack of quotations
```

I also tried adding the following to the Pipeline variables:

```
LibraryLocation = %LibraryLocation%
LibraryLocation = env:LibraryLocation
```

It seems the "value" is a literal in the Pipeline variables so none of the above worked.

It's as if this global system variable defined in Windows doesn't exist.

I tried searching for a solution but it seems that everything within a build pipeline is considered an "environment variable" and "system variables" have another connotation which seem to be predefined.  I read examples of using a PowerShell task to set it but I shouldn't have to do that as it is already set!

How do I get my build pipeline to recognize this custom environment variable set in the operating system?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you use microsoft-hosted agent or self-hosted agent?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT It's a self-hosted agent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was a setup issue. As best as I understood IT's explanation, although I set up the environment variable correctly, the job was being submitted to a different agent pool that was not aware of this environment variable. And now after their fix, as I suspected, there is no need to define a Pipeline variable or have a task to set the environment variable as it is already recognized by the build.

Answer (score 0):

As it is written [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#environment-variables)

> Environment variables are specific to the operating system you are using. They are injected into a pipeline in platform-specific ways. The format corresponds to how environment variables get formatted for your specific scripting platform.
>
> On UNIX systems (macOS and Linux), environment variables have the format $NAME. On Windows, the format is %NAME% for batch and $env:NAME in PowerShell.
>
> System and user-defined variables also get injected as environment variables for your platform. When variables are turned into environment variables, variable names become uppercase, and periods turn into underscores. For example, the variable name any.variable becomes the variable name $ANY_VARIABLE.

You should be able to access Windows env variable in one of this ways:

- %LIBRARYLOCATION%
- env:LIBRARYLOCATION

Which os this will work for you can depened how you call MSBuild.

You can check you variables calling `env | sort` from bash step.

And when I ran `%PATH%` from command line script I got:

[image]

and this when I ran '$env:PATH` from powershell task:

[image]

Comment: I read that documentation but am confused as to where it actually applies.  I'm not interested in a Bash, Command Line, or PowerShell task added to the pipeline.  I have $(LibraryLocation) embedded in my .vcxproj files but it is currently unrecognized when run through a Visual Studio task building my solution.  Do I need to add $(LibraryLocation) = %LibraryLocation% to the Pipeline variables?  Or is there some other mechanism?

Comment: I added %PATH% to the script in a Command Line Task and it failed with: ##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '1'.  The literal "%PATH%" was just output.  I see the "Environment Variables" drop down in the task, but again, that's just a key-value pair.